# When using features to manage deployment, should I break my functionality into many little features or one big feature?

Tags: 7, features

I'm relatively new to the [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module and I've read contradictory recommendations online regarding whether it's easiest to maintain A) one big feature or B) several smaller ***features*** and then a "***feature-controller***" type module that lists all the smaller features as dependencies.

A bit about my specific situation: I'm using a `local development -> dev server -> staging server -> live server` workflow.  This particular site will almost certainly be the only one of its kind that I ever develop; I do not intend to use the `features` I create for this site on any other sites.

This makes me lean toward doing everything in one big feature because I've had problems in the past where I accidentally defined the same rules in multiple features and gotten into trouble.  However, in terms of structure this seems wrong to me-- there are different features/functions so they ought to be divided into separate features.  On the other hand, I feel like by doing this I may just create additional work and overhead for myself that won't benefit anyone.

Which approach is easier to maintain in actual practice-- one big feature or many smaller ones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Make several little Features, split by conceptual layer**.

Advantages:

1. Granularity when reviewing Overrides and performing Reverts — so you don't *have* to revert everything at once.
2. Modularity — even if you don't plan to reuse individual components, breaking things down into discrete modules will help with maintainability.

For deploying a single site from development to test to production, we use the following taxonomy (where "site" is replaced with a unique machinename for the site) —

- `site_types` Feature — declares Content Types, Fields, ImageCache settings, [User Roles](http://drupal.org/project/role_export)
- `site_structure` Feature — declares Contexts, Views, Menus and [Menu Links](http://drupal.org/node/1283742), Blocks, User Permissions, Variables

  - depends on `site_types` Feature
- `site_content` Feature — declares [Nodes](http://drupal.org/project/uuid_features)

  - depends on `site_structure` Feature

If there are multiple distinct site sections (for example, Public vs Private), consider splitting things up further:

- `site_types` Feature
- `site_structure` Feature — declares structural components common to both Public and Private

  - depends on `site_types` Feature
- `site_public_structure` Feature

  - depends on `site_types` Feature
- `site_public_content` Feature

  - depends on `site_public_structure` Feature
- `site_private_structure` Feature

  - depends on `site_types` Feature
- `site_private_content` Feature

  - depends on `site_private_structure` Feature